# Jade template how to add text after tag on the same level

Tags: node.js, pug

I am try to get this to work in jade template:

html:

```
<li><i class="icon-comment"></i> 5</li>
```

jade:

```
li:i.icon-comment 5
```

ofcource 5 now is nested under i tag rather then li. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In my templates I do it like this:

```
li
  i.icon-comment
  |  5
```

Comment: nice thanks.. why is the pipe so magical? What does pipe mean again?

Comment: It just puts text after the previous tag. You can read about it in the docs [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#tag-text).

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways like:

1. Like the one shared with david using `|`

```
li
  i.icon-comment
  |  5
```

2. Add it in single line:

```
li #[i.icon-comment] 5
```